# Show data on Listview is duplication

Tags: android

I'm doing a app can update data every 1 minutes, data will from database mysql on server to show on listview of my app android. My problem is when show data the first is ok but when show data the second on listview, data of the first and the second is duplication.Can you help me!
Source code:

```
public class Hoadon extends Activity {
JSONArray jArray;
String result = null;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb = null;
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> al2 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> al3 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> al1a = new ArrayList<String>();
String date;
String name;
String address;
String url;
String code;
int responseCode;
private String IDinvoice;
private TimerTask mTimerTask;
private Timer t=new Timer();
private final Handler handler=new Handler();
private ListView listview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hoadon);
    int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
       setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
    }
    else {
       setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
    }
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://longvansolution.tk/monthlytarget.php");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    try {
        if (isNetworkAvailable() == true
                //&& responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK
                ) {
            //new LoadData().execute();
            al.clear();
            al1.clear();
            al2.clear();
            al3.clear();
            al1a.clear();

            doTimerTask();
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            ad.setMessage("No Internet Connection available!!!");
            ad.show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        IDinvoice = extras.getString("IDinvoice");
    }


}

public void doTimerTask(){
    mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {       
            public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                new LoadData().execute();
                                Log.d("TIMER", "TimerTask run");
                            }
                   });
            }};
        // public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period) 
        t.schedule(mTimerTask, 500, 10000);  // 
     }
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    //do something with bitmap
}
private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    @Override
    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                Hoadon.this, "", " Loading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
        this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            listview.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(Hoadon.this,
                    al.toArray(new String[al.size()]), al1a
                            .toArray(new String[al1a.size()]), al1
                            .toArray(new String[al1.size()]), al2
                            .toArray(new String[al2.size()])));
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String t = al3.get(position);
                    Intent i = new Intent(Hoadon.this,
                            Signature.class);
                    i.putExtra("url", t);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // HTTP post

        try {

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://longvansolution.tk/monthlytarget.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // buffered reader
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 80);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                String line = "0";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            try {
                jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    date = json_data.getString("date");
                    address = json_data.getString("address");
                    name = json_data.getString("name");
                    url = json_data.getString("url");
                    code = json_data.getString("code");
                    al.add(date);
                    al1a.add(code);
                    al1.add(name);
                    al2.add(address);
                    al3.add(url);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return null;

    }
}

public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    // if no network is available networkInfo will be null, otherwise check
    // if we are connected
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

        // Log.i("net status:", "Online...!!!");
        return true;
    }
    // Log.i("net status:", "offline...!!!");
    return false;
}
```

}

Source DataAdapter

```
public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
String[] date;
String[] code;
String[] address;
String[] name;

public DataAdapter(Context c, String[] date,String[] code, String[] name, String[] address) {
    this.date = date;
    this.code=code;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    mContext = c;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}

public void clearData() {
    // clear the data
    Arrays.fill(date, null);
    Arrays.fill(code, null);
    Arrays.fill(address, null);
    Arrays.fill(name, null);
}

public int getCount() {
    return date.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customgrid, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.code=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mahd);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);
        if (position == 0) {
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    try {

        holder.date.setText(date[position]);
        holder.code.setText(code[position]);
        holder.name.setText(name[position]);
        holder.address.setText(address[position]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView date,code;
    TextView name, address;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should clear your arralist every LoadData  task.

```
try {
 jArray = new JSONArray(result);
 JSONObject json_data = null;

 al.clear();
 al1.clear();
 al2.clear();
 al3.clear();
 al1a.clear();

 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                date = json_data.getString("date");
                address = json_data.getString("address");
                name = json_data.getString("name");
                url = json_data.getString("url");
                code = json_data.getString("code");
                al.add(date);
                al1a.add(code);
                al1.add(name);
                al2.add(address);
                al3.add(url);
            }
```